# Approximation for Coupon Collector Probability

Tags: probability, random, coupon-collector

I was calculating the probability to draw all items in a list of N items, by picking one randomly, replacing it in the list, etc. (Edit: It's the Coupon collector Problem)

I found [this formula](http://www.dcode.fr/probabilites-tirage) after *n* picking.

$$ \sum_{i=0}^N (-1)^{N-i}{\binom{N}{i}}\left(\frac{i}{N}\right)^n $$

But, I have to calculate this formula with N > 1000000000 in a java program so to avoid a huge loop (the sum). I'm looking for a simplification, any approximation formula will help me.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

Comment: You're right it is the same problem, but I don't see any formula I can use on this page.

Comment: See 5.2.1 here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.05387.pdf

Comment: For large $n$, see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1755398: In this case, the probability not to draw all items is approximately the expected number of undrawn items.